# Why does the "Move" menu requires pressing an arrow key first to move the window with mouse?

Tags: windows

Sometimes apps misbehave and their title bar is placed out of the screen. When this happens I often use Alt+Space to show the system menu, and select `Move` and then move the window.

But there is one thing that bothers me. When I select `Move`, the cursor changes to a four-directional cursor, but it does not move the window. I have to press an arrow key, and then the mouse moves the window. Why is it so? I wish I could move the window without pressing an arrow key.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is not a general method for moving the window.
It is rather an emergency method for moving off-screen windows back to the screen.

As the window in question is not visible, one cannot use the mouse on it,
so there no need for a mouse interface.

If you want to move a visible window with the mouse, the right way is to drag it
by its title. There is no need in this case to pass through the System Menu
of the application window.

Comment: Yeah, I am using it for "emergency". But I need mouse to move the misbehaving window to the precise location I want. I could use arrow keys alone, but using arrow keys is slow compared to mouse. That is why I just press an arrow key single time, and then use mouse. I cannot click the tile bar because the title bar is invisible.